# Airflow, how to pass variables from BashOperator task to another

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to figure out the most generic/effective way to pass variables from one BashOperator task to another. I came up with a solution, where I push the output of the first BashOperator task to xcom. This string is then pulled by a PythonOperator task that parses the string to a key-value pairs that are then pushed to xcom. Finally these k-v pairs can be pulled and used by the second BashOperator task.

I would like to have some comments from the more experienced airflow users, is this approach overly complicated or is it ok?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import datetime as dt 
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago    

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019,10,14,10,0),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('communication-between-tasks-v1',
      catchup=False,
      default_args=default_args,
      schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *')

def parse_function(**context):
    ti = context['ti']
    msg = ti.xcom_pull('start_task')
    parsed_output_parameters = dict([x.split('=') for x in msg.split()])

    # Option1: Dictionary parsed from the string is pushed to xcom
    ti.xcom_push(key='parameters', value=parsed_output_parameters)

    # Option2: We can push every key value separately
    for k, v in parsed_output_parameters.items():
        ti.xcom_push(key=k, value=v)


start_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    bash_command='echo "FILE1=file1.h5 FILE2=file2.txt VARIABLE=400"',
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

parse = PythonOperator(
    task_id='parse',
    python_callable=parse_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

end_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='end_task',
    bash_command='echo start_task params: {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="parse", 
    key="parameters")["FILE1"] }} \
    {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="parse", key="FILE2") }}',
    dag=dag
)

start_task >> parse >> end_task
```

Answer (score 2):

Xcom works best with really small amounts of data being passed & should be used sparingly (as it is all written to the airflow database).

If you have 2 different BashOperator tasks & you want to pass data from one to the other, why not just write the output to a file in the first task & read it in with the second? (You could include a line in the second BashOperator task that verifies that the file contains data & `rm` the file after reading its contents.)

Comment: This approach will not be useful when using Operators in different machines or pods

Comment: This approach is very useful when there is any kind of shared storage (nfs, hdfs, s3, etc.)